# Replace different characters using Regex

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove all single comments `//` and block comments `/* */` of a line inside a string. 
However, if those comments are inside the characters `''`, `""`, `[]` and/or ``` `` ``` it should not be removed.

Examples:

```
='a' &
'//b/*aasdsa //dsfds*/'& //comment
'//d' /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ & '//e' & /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ 
& 'c'
[// /* [] */] & h
`// /* [] */` & p
```

Should be:

```
='a' &
'//b'& 
'//d'  & '//e' &  
& 'c'
 & h
 & p
```

I have tried different solutions but I haven't got too far.

```
let text = "='a' &
'//b'& //comment expression 
'//d' /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ & '//e' & /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ 
& 'c'";
let arrayText = text.split('\n');
arrayText = arrayText.filter(a => a.indexOf('//') !== 0);
arrayContent = arrayContent.map(x =>
x.replace(/[^\(?<=\').*(?=\'$)|\(?<=\[).*(?=\]$](\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*)/gm, ''));
text = arrayContent.join(' ');
```

With the solution that I tried I just got the following:

Text:

```
='a' &
'//b/*aasdsa //dsfds*/'& //comment
'//d' /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ & '//e' & /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ 
& 'c'
[// /* [] */] & h
`// /* [] */` & p
```

Result with my solution (that doesn't work)

```
='a' &
'//b'&
'//d' & '//e' & 
& 'c'
[//]
```

Expected result:

```
='a' &
'//b/*aasdsa //dsfds*/'& 
'//d'  & '//e' &  
& 'c'
[// /* [] */] & h
`// /* [] */` & p
```

I would appreciate if somebody can point me what I am missing or any other hint.

Comment: Your 2nd sample input contains a block comment inside of the `'//b'` string that gets removed. Is that intentional?

Comment: IMO regex isn't the proper tool for this.  I would consider using a tokenizer/parser instead.  The regex you have is already heinously complex and difficult to understand, and I fully expect you will continually be running into inputs that breaks the regex.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287216/removing-comments-using-regex for an example of how much more complex your regex can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, regex isn't a proper tool for something normally done by tokenizers. For this particular use case, you could write a simple rule-based parser like this:

```js
const rules = [
  { start: '[', end: ']', remove: false },
  { start: "'", end: "'", remove: false },
  { start: '"', end: '"', remove: false },
  { start: '`', end: '`', remove: false },
  { start: '//', end: {EOL:true}, remove: true },
  { start: '/*', end: '*/', remove: true },
];

function removeComments(str) {
  let start = -1, rule = null;
  //iterate over the input, character by character
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if(!rule) {
      //if not currently in a 'group' (either string or comment) search for one
      let test = rules.find(r => str.slice(i).startsWith(r.start));
      if(test) {
        rule = test;
        start = i;
      }
    } else {
      //currently in a string or comment, check if it ended
      let end = -1;
      if(str.slice(i).startsWith(rule.end)) {
        end = i + rule.end.length;
      } else if(rule.end.EOL && (str.slice(i).startsWith('\n') || str.slice(i).startsWith('\r\n') || i == str.length - 1)) {
        //special handling for line comments which can end on many conditions
        end = i + 1; 
      }
      if(end > -1) {
        if(rule.remove) {
          //modify str if it was a comment rule - cut out the comment
          str = str.slice(0,start) + str.slice(end);
          i -= end - start;
        }
        rule = null;
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
}

["='a' &",
"'//b/*aasdsa //dsfds*/'& //comment",
"'//d' /*aasdsa //dsfds*/ & '//e' & /*aasdsa //dsfds*/",
"& 'c'",
"[// /* [] */] & h",
"`// /* [] */` & p"].forEach(str => console.log(removeComments(str)));
```

Note that the output differs from your expected output, because your expected output does things that defy the rules you laid out in the question - it removes everything bordered by `[]` and ````. as well as block comments contained in strings `'/* */'`.

Comment: @Joe This is already what is done by my solution. I don't understand what other requirements need to be added?